# setxkbmap is not running on startup in rc.local

Tags: startup, init.d

I am trying to run

```
setxkbmap -option caps:escape
```

in my rc.local file under /etc/init.d/ in Kubuntu 15.04, and no matter where I put it, beginning or end, or with exec in front of it, it is not running. Basically, I want to be able to run gvim with caps as escape, and I don't really want to put this into .bashrc as that will run every time I open a terminal (unnecessary) and also I would like to be able to run gvim without first opening bash, and still having caps as escape.

This command works fine in the command line.

The whole rc.local looks like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rc.local
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Run /etc/rc.local if it exist
### END INIT INFO


/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option caps:escape
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start() {
       if [ -x /etc/rc.local ]; then
               [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_begin_msg 
"Running local boot scripts (/etc/rc.local)"
               /etc/rc.local
               ES=$?
               [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 
$ES
               return $ES
       fi
}

case "$1" in
   start)
       do_start
       ;;
   restart|reload|force-reload)
       echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
       exit 3
       ;;
   stop)
       ;;
   *)
       echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
       exit 3
       ;;
esac
```

Am I doing something wrong? Anything else to do to get the same result? I am not running Unity so compizconfig won't work.

Comment: Try this post [here] (https://askubuntu.com/a/956271/730176).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think that it is useful to run any programs with 'x' in their names before the actual X GUI session is started.

Put it into 'Startup Applications' (or whatever it's called in KDE).