# Remapping Keys - Xubuntu/Awesome

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout, awesome, remapping, evdev

Currently on Xubuntu and I want to use Awesome WM, but Awesome is highly dependent on the Windows key, which my keyboard does not have. So I'm trying to remap the Win key to Right Alt with no success yet. I've been searching and reading Man Pages for a couple hours now with no luck. Ive tried using xmodmap, which I understand is now obsolete, and also setxkbmap. I've also attempted to alter evdev.lst with no success.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Correctly all this is done with the help of `xkbcomp`. The name of the utility, like the man to it, gives little information about what it does. Allegedly translates text descriptions of the keyboard layout into a binary format. But in fact, it also loads them.
Reading https://lampjs.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/remapchange-your-secondaryusb-keyboard-keys/    https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=53137.0

more  https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2014-April/056564.html
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2014-April/056565.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ok.I.tried.the.method.described.in.the.second.link.and.it.didn't.work.but.it.seems.to.have.disabled.my.spacebar...The.spacebar.still.selects.text.and.opens.the.window.menu,.but.as.you.can.see.it.does.not.make.spaces.

Comment: OK. Describe what you did and attach the modified files. It is necessary to see what led to this result

Comment: try return original mylayout.xkb, which you had to backup.   more https://askubuntu.com/questions/956243/trying-to-remap-my-left-super-key-also-called-windows-key-to-left-or-right-con?rq=1